# How to get all entries for 4 weeks sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I get all records from a table from this week and the next 3 weeks, in total 4 weeks.
This will gave me this week.

```
SELECT *, FROM_UNIXTIME(date) as time  FROM `events` WHERE 
WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = WEEK(NOW())
AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = MONTH(NOW())
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Any ideas on how to get the data for the next 3 weeks.

Comment: I've removed the conficting tags here. Please tag appropriately and tag only the technologies you are *really* using and asking about. Tagging MySQL and SQL Server confuses matters, and I'm not sure what the PHP Library MySQLi has to do with the problem above. It *appears* you are using MySQL here based on the syntax.

Comment: The `FROM_UNIXTIME` function exists in various DBMS like [tag:mysql] or [tag:databricks-sql]. Please [edit] and tag with your DBMS, so we can find a specific solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a time range:

```
WHERE date BETWEEN 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE())) DAY)) -- beginning of current week
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) + 28) DAY)) -- beginning of 4 weeks after
```

Comment: Thank you I been struggling all day with this